# JSP - Get score from a jsp quiz application

Tags: java, database, jsp, get

Hi I'm creating a quiz application in jsp and am using different jsp pages for every question. I'd like to keep a score after each question is answered. My problem is that I'm picking random answers from a database, within which lies the correct answer too. Since I can't guess which letter the correct answer will appear on, could you suggest what I should do? I am posting the first and second question jsp's to give you an idea of how I'm doing it:

q1.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Random"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="org.me.jsp.beans.WordBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<!--This JSP acts as the first question in a multiple choice quiz, with the user
asked to submit their answer to the question-->

<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id = "wordData" scope = "request"
             class = "org.me.jsp.beans.WordDataBean" />
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Big Java Quiz, question 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%if (request.getParameter("choice").equals("N")) {
                out.print("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=options.jsp'/>");
            }
            //Redirects user back to index if they did not want to take quiz%>
        <form action="q2.jsp" method="POST">
            <%
                List<WordBean> wordList = wordData.getWordList();
                List<String> answersList = new ArrayList<String>();
                Random random = new Random();
                Random forAnswers = new Random();

                WordBean goodOne = wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size()));
                //take it out from the list
                wordList.remove(goodOne);
                //add it to the answers list
                answersList.add(goodOne.getGermanName());
                WordBean fakeOne = wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size()));
                //take it out from the list
                wordList.remove(fakeOne);
                //add it to the answers list
                answersList.add(fakeOne.getGermanName());
                WordBean fakeTwo = wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size()));
                //take it out from the list
                wordList.remove(fakeTwo);
                //add it to the answers list
                answersList.add(fakeTwo.getGermanName());

            %>What is the English word for the German word <%=goodOne.getEnglishName()%>?<br>

                <%
                    char letter = 'A';
                    for (String answer : answersList) {
                %>
                <input type="radio" name="q1Answer" value=""/><label for="<%=letter%>"><%=letter%>)<%=answersList.get(forAnswers.nextInt(3))%>  /> 
                    <% //point to the next letter
                            letter++;
                        }
                        %>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

q2.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : q2
    Created on : 06-May-2012, 18:54:32
    Author     : encore
--%>

<!--This JSP acts as the second question in a multiple choice quiz, with the user
asked to submit their answer to the question-->

<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Big Java Quiz, question 2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%int score = 0;
        if(request.getParameter("q1Answer").equals("C"))
            score++; //Increments score if answer submitted was correct%>
        <form action="q3.jsp" method="POST">
            Your current score is: <%out.print(score);%>/20
            <input type="hidden" name="q2Score" value="<%out.print(score);%>"/>
            <!--Hidden button allows score to be accessed by next JSP-->
            <b>Question 2.</b> When an exception is generated it is said to have been _________?<br/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="q2Answer" value="A"/><label for="A">A) Built</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="q2Answer" value="B"/><label for="B">B) Thrown</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="q2Answer" value="C"/><label for="C">C) Caught</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="q2Answer" value="D"/><label for="D">D) Detected</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: the form of the second question will obviously be changed to something else, currently I'm concentrating on getting the score .

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If it's a random quiz, and the quiz is multiple choice, then you will be picking random *questions* from the database. When you retrieve the random question, you will also be retrieving all of the answers, including the correct one.  You should therefore have all of the information you need to make *any* decision.

Comment: no no no, the question is fixed and will be "What's the english word for the german word [get the word from the database]?"

Then I generate three random answers with words taken from that same database, upon which is the corresponding answer to the question too. ;)

Comment: I can't tell in which of the three possible letters the correct answer will appear. I need a command that gets the one that equals the corresponding answer of the question

Comment: So instead of `request.getParameter("q1Answer").equals("C")` I need something that will replace "C"

Comment: Generally speaking, when you score a quiz, you will be looking up the correct answers from the database, and comparing them with the responses the user gives you.  Presumably, when they select A, B, C or D, you know which word corresponds to the letter they chose.  You also know which word is the correct one.  If the word they chose equals the correct word, then their answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the page for Q1, where you should know the correct answer, put it in the session and then retrieve it in the next page.